# Button does not disabled and text value does'nt change after click

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I basically have a table that have a 1-click apply button function for a job board. I wrote some ajax function code and jquery so that whenever user click on button, the button will be disabled and text change. Right now the ajax button did work and there is a change in a database after click but I cannot get that button disabled and change the text. Please help.

Here is what Ajax link button looks like:

```
  @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
 @Ajax.ActionLink("1-Click-Apply", "OneClickApply", new { id = item.PositionID }, new AjaxOptions
 {
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       Confirm = "Are you sure you want to apply for " + item.Title + "?",
       OnSuccess = "deactive"
  }, new { @class = "btn btn-info float-right", id = "oneClick" + item.PositionID, style = "margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px" })
  }
```

Here is the jquery part:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function deactive(data) {
        $('#oneClick' + data.id)addClass('disabled').text("Applied");

    }
</script>
```

This is the error im getting:[image: https://i.imgur.com/o23bHUZ.jpg]
This is what my UI looks like:[image: https://i.imgur.com/r3IASim.jpg]

Code about 1 click button:

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]      
    public JsonResult OneClickApply(int id)
    {
        Application ctx = new Application();
        Position position = db.Positions.Find(id);
        OpenPosition open = db.OpenPositions.Where(op => op.PositionID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        //open.PositionID = open.OpenPositionID;

        string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        UserDetail currentUser = db.UserDetails.Where(ud => ud.UserID == userID).FirstOrDefault();


        ctx.OpenPositionID = open.OpenPositionID;
        ctx.UserID = currentUser.UserID;
        ctx.ApplicationDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
        ctx.ResumeFileName = currentUser.ResumeFileName;
        ctx.ApplicationStatusID = 1;
        db.Applications.Add(ctx);
        db.SaveChanges();
        string confirmMessage = string.Format("You have just applied for '{0}'!", open.Position.Title);

        return Json(new { id = id, message = confirmMessage});
    }
```

**That whole page of cshtml**

```
    @model PagedList.IPagedList<JobBoard.DATA.EF.Position>
         @using System;
         @using PagedList.Mvc
       @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }
        <section class="section-hero overlay inner-page bg-image" 
         style="background-image: url('/Content/images/hero_1.jpg');" 
         id="home-section">
         <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                   <h1 class="text-white font-weight-bold">Admin Panel</h1>
                    <div class="custom-breadcrumbs">
                         <a href="/Home/Index">Home</a> <span class="mx-2 slash">/</span>
                         <a href="/Home/Positions">Positions</a> <span class="mx-2 slash">/</span>
                    <span class="text-white"><strong>@ViewBag.Title</strong></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
           <section class="site-section" id="next-section">
           <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12 mb-5 mb-lg-0">


                   <p>
                       @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
                   </p>

                   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Positions", FormMethod.Get))
                {
                    <div style="border:2px solid lightblue; margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;padding:15px">
                        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                    </div>

                }
                <span style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

                    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
                </span>
                <a href="#">content</a>
                @if (Model.Count() > 0)
                {
                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Title
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Job Description
                                </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="/Positions/Details/@item.PositionID"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:270px">

                                        @*@item.JobDescription.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.JobDescription.Length, 200)) ...*@



                                        @Html.Raw(item.JobDescription.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.JobDescription.Length, 200))) ...


                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Manager"))
                                        {
                                            <span class="float-right" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px">
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PositionID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="float-right" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px"> @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PositionID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })</span>

                                        }
                                        <span class="float-right" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px"> @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PositionID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning " })</span>

                                        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                                        {
                                            @Ajax.ActionLink("1-Click-Apply", "OneClickApply", new { id = item.PositionID }, new AjaxOptions
                                       {
                                           HttpMethod = "POST",
                                           Confirm = "Are you sure you want to apply for " + item.Title + "?",
                                           OnSuccess = "deactive"
                                       }, new { @class = "btn btn-info float-right", id = "oneClick" + item.PositionID, style = "margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px" })
                                        }




                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>Sorry your criteria did not return any result.Please try again or or hit "Go!" to refresh the page</p>
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
          @section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function deactive(data) {
            $('#oneClick' + data.id).addClass('disabled').text("Applied");

        }
    </script>


    }
```

Comment: Can you also post the code of the action `OneClickApply` ?

Comment: @Keith Just edited the post

Answer (score 0):

In the ajax `OnSuccess` you're not passing the position id for the function `deactivate` thats why your script does nothing because function parameter `data` is null

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("1-Click-Apply", "OneClickApply", new { id = item.PositionID }, new AjaxOptions
 {
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       Confirm = "Are you sure you want to apply for " + item.Title + "?",
       OnSuccess = "deactive"
  }, new { @class = "btn btn-info float-right", id = "oneClick" + item.PositionID, style = "margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px" })
  }
```

so to correct this you should call `deactive()` with `PositionId` parameter;

```
OnSuccess = "deactive('" + item.PositionID + "')"
```

and then in your script you can access the id by doing

```
function deactive(id) {
        $('#oneClick' + id)addClass('disabled').text("Applied");

    }
```

Your Ajax Helper should look like this;

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("1-Click-Apply", "OneClickApply", new { id = item.PositionID }, new AjaxOptions
 {
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       Confirm = "Are you sure you want to apply for " + item.Title + "?",
       OnSuccess = "deactive('" + item.PositionID + "')"
  }, new { @class = "btn btn-info float-right", id = "oneClick" + item.PositionID, style = "margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px" })
  }
```